# I was robbed of my hard-earned unicoins!

Tags: discussion, unicoins

I purchased an item with my unicoins, then I realized I no longer needed it... I was so happy when I saw "Recycle" option! I assumed it was return/refund option (and a charge of 10 unicoins for the service kind of confirmed this in my mind, you know - restocking fee).

To my dismay, not only I was not refunded original purchase price, but I was charged for this recycling scam anyway!

I demand justice and my 60 unicoins back!

Comment: Gah, this happened to me too with 90 + 10 unicorns.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your unicoins are not lost! They simply turned to stone. You can get them back by breaking the stones in the mining page.

Comment: I did try this approach, but after a while I found it quite painful (even though I had descent training for this exercise on my Pebble app http://goo.gl/IGKZyc) there must be another way.

Comment: Try using multi-touch Android. By combining all your fingers together you can mine up to 10 times faster.

Comment: What a brilliant idea! Thanks, I will give it a try when I get a chance and let you know the results. Gotta love the technology!

Comment: I am back in business! I see bright future for Unicoins; I just know they're here to stay as a solid currency forever. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

Please hold tight Yuriy.  Stack Exchange had certain old-format unicoin wallets which were used in the past and which, Stack Exchange thought, no longer held any unicoins.  These wallets were rescanned and were found to hold 200,000 unicoins.

Stack Exchange had previously disclosed the disappearance of 2 trillion unicoins.  In order to be fair to all of our users and their lost unicoins, your pro-rated return based on 5 million owners of the lost unicoins should be .000006 unicoins.  We expect to deliver these back to you...never.

Comment: Wait.. are u sure your math is correct?

Comment: Not even remotely sure.

Answer (score -1):

I, riding on my rainbow unicorn across the rainbow tubes of the rainbow internet into your computer, stole your unicoins. BWAHAHAHAHAHA.

Comment: Give'em back!!!